# I can't change permanently the background color of a simple html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

when I click in the button the backgrounf color of the change but after one seconde it disappear

## this is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ex7</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <script>
            function changerCouleur() {
                document.bgColor= "#FFFggF";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
          couleur  <input type="text" > <br>
          <button onclick="changerCouleur()">changer couleur </button>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but still: `#FFFggF` is not a valid color value. (i.e. the "g" in there)

Comment: The default action of a button is to submit the form. This effectively reloads the page resetting the background.

Comment: JavaScript loads fresh. You would need, at the least, to use something like `localStorage`.

Comment: For the button add `type="button"` that way the page doesn't refresh. When buttons are wrapped in a form, they will submit by default

Comment: @Johannes the problem is not about the color value

Comment: yes, that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already have an answer, but there is no `localStorage` mechanism with that example. You may want to study the following structure.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{ // load
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
// small Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load event *(except the // end load line)*
const bg = I('bg'), ch_bg = I('ch_bg'), gut = I('gut'), gutS = gut.style;
bg.oninput = function(){
  if(this.value.trim().length < 3){
    rC(this, 'good');
  }
  else{
    aC(this, 'good');
  }
}
ch_bg.onclick = ()=>{
  if(hC(bg, 'good')){
    let color =  bg.value.trim();
    bg.value = color; gutS.backgroundColor = color; localStorage.bgColor = color;
  }
}
if(localStorage.bgColor){
  gutS.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgColor;
}
else{
  localStorage.bgColor = '#aaa';
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; border:0; box-sizing:border-box; outline:none; overflow:hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
  -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; user-select:none;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#aaa;
}
.bar{
  position:relative; width:100%; height:39px; background:#ccc; padding:3px; border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
.bar>*{
  position:relative; display:inline-block; height:32px;
}
.bar>*>img{
  width:32px; height:32px;
}
.bar h1{
  font:bold 27px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; margin-left:3px;
}
.guts{
  width:100%; max-height:calc(100% - 39px); background:#aaa; padding:7px 7px 0; overflow-y:auto;
}
.guts *{
  font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
label>span{
  cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; height:27px; color:#fff; text-shadow:-1px 0 #000,0 1px #000,1px 0 #000,0 -1px #000; float:left;
}
label>input,label>select,label>textarea{
  width:100%; height:38px; background:#fff; color:#000; padding:5px; border:1px solid #c00; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:none; margin:2px 0 5px 0; -moz-user-select:text; -ms-user-select:text; -webkit-user-select:text; user-select:text;
}
label>input.good,label>select.good,label>textarea.good{
  border-color:#0c0;
}
label>textarea{
  height:auto;
}
label>input[type=button],label>button{
  cursor:pointer; height:auto; background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; font:bold 28px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; border:1px solid #007; border-radius:10px;
}
#ch_bg{
  margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='bar'><h1>Color Change Example</h1></div>
    <div class='guts' id='gut'>
      <label><span>couleur</span><input id='bg' type='text' value='' /><input id='ch_bg' type='button' value='changer couleur' /></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's that hahaha

Comment: Try it on `localhost`. Type in your color then hit the button. Navigate away from the page and you'll see that the color is the same as when you set it. It's really just a learning example for you.

Answer (score 0):

#FFFggF is not a valid color code.

Please try this code:

```js
function changerCouleur() {
                document.body.style.background = "#ff9933";
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ex7</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <form onSubmit="return false">
          couleur  <input type="text" > <br>
          <button onclick="changerCouleur();">changer couleur </button>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I added the attribute onSubmit="return false" to the form because otherwise every time you click on the button the page is reloaded

Comment: thank you Jackom the problem is resolved when I added the attribute onSubmit="return false"